# Is the following analogy right or did i misunderstood something

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter

I was searching for the difference between an programming-language and a script-language.

Here is my analogy, how I understood it:

I am a CPU which only can execute commands written in the German language(machine language).

Now somebody could write commands in english.

The compiler will translate the whole code into german, so i can execute the commands, one after another.
This is how a programming-language works...you have code written in the programming-language and you need a compiler, which translates this code into machine code, so the computer is able to execute these commands.
This translation is only made once.

The interpreter is like a third person, which translates a command after another, so that me (CPU) can understand the english language (script language).

For me to execute the commands, is the interpreter essential or otherwise I do not understand the language (script language), but for a compiled (translated) command text, there is no need for any interpreter, because the text is in my own language.

If I made a mistake, please let me know.

Comment: You could say that x86 is a script - it's just the native script of the processor, and unlike a Python script, it's not very readable for humans.

Comment: If you just want to discuss your fairy-tale than it is off-topic due to http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask: _..there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”.._ Otherwise please explain more clearly what is the programming problem you need to get resolved

Comment: Your question is probably better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just getting down votes for such a simple question...silly. Nevertheless, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is an analogy, so it is *approximately* right (but "the evil is in the details").

Notice that a language is a *specification*, often in a document in English (e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or `ISO/IEC 9899:2011` for [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)). You don't need a computer to "run" some program in some language (you could unethically use a bunch of human slaves, or run the program in your head). A language may have several implementations (some are interpreters, others are compilers). You could consider the machine code as written in some machine language (this was actually the case for the first computers like [ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC); in the 1940s it was programmed by humans in machine language; as a teenager in 1975 I programmed in a museum the [IBM1620](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1620) in machine language).

However, there are rare cases where you still want to translate your own machine code: imagine a binary program using some inefficient opcodes. You could have some other program translating these into some more appropriate machine code.

Read wikipages on [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [interpreters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29), [machine code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code), [compiler optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization), [object code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code), [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode), [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), [emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator), [microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture), [micro-operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-operation), [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), [partial evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation), [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval), [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

Many compiled languages have some interpreted aspects (e.g. [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) in C). Some language implementations are able to generate machine code on the fly, notably (for [Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)) [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/). So the difference between interpreters and compilers is blurry.

Even with compiled languages, on some operating systems, a program could generate some code (e.g. in C or C++) on the fly then compile and [dynamically load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) it. I am doing such things in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/).

Some scripting languages are translated to bytecode or even to machine code, depending upon the implementation (e.g. [V8 javascript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)). In my opinion [turing-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) is a more important feature (shared by most scripting languages and compiled languages) than being compiled.

I am not sure that there is a clear distinction between scripting languages and compiled languages, notably because a compiler is an *implementation* of some language (and the *same* language could also have an *interpreter*: [Ocaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) has *both* `ocaml` - a toplevel interpreter - `ocamlc` - a bytecode compiler - and `ocamlopt` - a native compiler -); I see on the contrary a continuum between compiled and interpreted implementations.

Comment: Aren't x86 and x64 also scripts? You could say that the sequence of opcodes is a script that the processor follows. Granted, they're not readable for humans...

Comment: Yes, you can say that; and ENIAC was programmed in machine language.

Comment: So is there really a division between script/non-script? The only division is that one of those scripts happens to be the native script of the CPU, while all others need to be translated to that one for the CPU to follow.

Answer (score 0):

nowadays the distinction between interpreters and compilers is not that clear anymore because tools are much more sophisticated. eg. java virtual machine can compile read source files, compile them to bytecode, run them, in the middle of run compile some part of it to machine code, after a while decompile it back to byte code, run, compile again to machine code etc. you can also change the code without stopping the program